# Shifting Buffer to the left, scrolling a string on LED panel?

Tags: c, arrays, text, scroll, buffer

I have a function that I dont quite understand

There are 109 addresses from 0 to 110.

How is this code shifting text to the left ?

```
b=0;
while(b<109)
{
  Display_Buffer[b] = Display_Buffer[b+1];
  b++;
}
```

if b starts at 0, then b+1 should scroll the text to the RIGHT instead ??? Or am I getting this wrong ? because at 0, b+1 means the address is 1, if its b-1, then the address should be 110 (hence scrolling left) ... But thats not the case here, can someone provide a rough explanation ?

The display_buffer contains the string information stored in its arrays.

--

EDIT

Thanks guys !! What if I replaced Display_Buffer[b+1] with [b-1] ... will this reverse the process ? how ?

Okay I realized I have to add b=109 and while (b!=0) .. or else that wont make sense.

But still, if Display_Buffer[109]=Display_Buffer[108], does that mean it will produce the same effect as you guys answered but in reverse ?

Comment: You're just copying elements from `b+1` to `b`, i.e. moving everything *down* by one element.

Comment: You're reading the assignment backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                           /*  [a|b|c|d|e|f|...]   */
Display[0] = Display[1]    /*  [b|b|c|d|e|f|...]   */
Display[1] = Display[2]    /*  [b|c|c|d|e|f|...]   */
Display[2] = Display[3]    /*  [b|c|d|d|e|f|...]   */
//     ...
                           /*  [b|c|d|e|f|g|...]   */
```

When you do this kind of things, you must take care to not overwrite from the wrong direction ...

```
                           /*  [a|b|c|d|e|f|...]   */
Display[1] = Display[0]    /*  [a|a|c|d|e|f|...]   */
Display[2] = Display[1]    /*  [a|a|a|d|e|f|...]   */
//     ...
                           /*  [a|a|a|a|a|a|...]   */
```

To do the same thing from the end

```
Display[last] = Display[last-1]    /*  [a|b|c|d|e|f|...]   */
//     ...
Display[2] = Display[1]            /*  [a|b|b|c|d|e|...]   */
Display[1] = Display[0]            /*  [a|a|b|c|d|e|...]   */
Display[0] = ' '                   /*  [ |a|b|c|d|e|...]   */
```

Comment: Thanks guys !! What if I replaced Display_Buffer[b+1] with [b-1] ... will this reverse the process ? how ?

Comment: Perfect, you get the answer for replying to my second question :D THanks

Answer (score 5):

Each position is assigned the value of the position to the right of it, so the effect is a scroll to the left.

Consider this awesome ASCII art:

```
         0  1  2  3  4
Before: [h][e][l][l][o]
 After: [e][l][l][o][ ]
```

The slot at position 0 is set to the value of slot 1, so 'h' becomes 'e', and so on.

Comment: Thanks guys !! What if I replaced Display_Buffer[b+1] with [b-1] ... will this reverse the process ? how ?

Answer (score 2):

It's setting the byte at position `b` to be equal to the byte at position `b+1`

so bytes slowly move left, one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Lets say `Display_Buffer` was `"abcd"` initially. So `Display_Buffer[0] = 'a', Display_Buffer[1] = 'b'` etc. Now what your are doing is `DisplayBuffer[0] = DisplayBuffer[1]` i.e. replacing 'a' with 'b' and similarly 'b' with 'c' and 'c' with 'd'. This produces the effect of text shifting to the left.

Comment: Thanks guys !! What if I replaced Display_Buffer[b+1] with [b-1] ... will this reverse the process ? how ?